How to install gcc with no cable plugged in on ubuntu live server 22.04?

There is no network connected

An extra usb device which can carry files

A windows11 computer which can connect wifi



Attention: please do not advise using apt install

Set up WSL or a VM to get Ubuntu on your Windows system, then use https://askubuntu.com/a/129543/158442 or https://askubuntu.com/a/72270/158442 to use apt to get the packages, copy them to the target system using your USB device and then use apt on the target device to install them

apt will (if given a path) install already downloaded packages, however you must direct it to do that as by default it downloads then installs (requiring internet). Your alternative is to just use dpkg, but also don't forget BOTH require all dependencies to also be installed, as if they aren't pre-installed or installed via your command (at the same time) it'll want to go to the internet to download them for you.

The algorithm is the single vector graph, and I tried many times, always got errors, and there might be circular dependency packages, just stuck here, sudo dpkg -i <pkg> is the way i install the dependency pkg now, and wonder some time: it may occur when somebody like me want to resolve this package installing issue ! I resolve the wireless-tools and wpasupplicant, the wireless env is just leave to the rtl 8852be adapter, which i found in the github, but must to be built with gcc

one answer is keryx, seems like to take effect to resolve gcc installing issue, which is not usable on windows11 .... tried many versions, 0.92.5, 0.92.3, 0.91, but it just does not work, couldn't create project or stuck in the start ui, or could not launch ...

Your command can install MANY packages at once; and your dependencies only need to be pre-installed, OR installed with the same command, ie. dpkg allows you to install a very long list of packages in a single command! so why would order matter? given you can install them all at the same time?  (the dpkg command will sort order out providing all are available in command line or pre-installed)

i tried, carry all the possible debian pkgs with usb into the ubuntu computer, and do the command: sudo dpkg -i *.deb, but got errors, andfailed

thank u all, i have resolved the issue by the advices you provide, i write some nodejs scripts to download the pkgs i need by dpkg -i *.deb in a folder, which carried by a usb !

From any computer with an internet connection, go to this site:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/gcc

Download the necessary packages and take them with a USB to your server and install them with dpkg.

aha... there are dependencies with the gcc, and must resolve them before compile and build, so this is the crucial question i want to resolve !

thank you for your help
